# Keyboard and On Screen Keyboard Not Working On Ubuntu 22.04 When Xorg is enabled and unable to turn off Xorg

Tags: keyboard, xorg, wayland

I am using a dual boot machine in which I have the Windows 10 OS and also the Ubuntu 22.04 OS

A few days ago I encountered an issue in which after I pass the lock screen page, any response from the keyboard is not responding ( this included on-screen keyboard and any external keyboard attached )

I try to change keyboard and restart a few times but nothing fix the issue, then I check at the right bottom corner on the first screen that appear after linux successful boot there is   a selection whether I want to choose "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu Xorg" then I noticed that If I choose Ubuntu Xorg this is what causing the error, I change to Ubuntu as this one able to fix the issue I am having

Then today I noticed in a google meet the screen sharing become black, and apps that I frequently used called VokoscreenNG, its ui/layout becomes weird and unable to select settings to screen record

So I search on internet and found this fixture

[https://superuser.com/questions/1729457/google-meet-share-screen-black-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts#:~:text=Just%20setting%20chrome%3A%2F%2Fflags,X11%20as%20the%20display%20manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1729457/google-meet-share-screen-black-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts#:%7E:text=Just%20setting%20chrome%3A%2F%2Fflags,X11%20as%20the%20display%20manager).

I follow the steps in which I edit the file at `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line `#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

Now after I reboot I am having a problem in which

- All kind of keyboard now is not working
- I am unable to change selection back to the normal Ubuntu, its like I am forced to use the Ubuntu Xorg, thus causing problem

I am posting this question using my Windows 10 while still figuring out way how to edit or revert back my Ubuntu settings to previous working state

I see a lot solution but require typing, I am unable to do the typing as any kind of keyboard is not responding in my ubuntu thus solution that involve typing will not work

FYI, my mouse is working fine

I am trying to find ways to edit the ubuntu file from my Windows 10, still checking on this while writing this question

Appreciate help from anyone

My device details:-

- Processors : AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics
- GPU : AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Use Ctrl+Alt+F2 and get to the tty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue on the keyboard is caused by Typing Assist configuration located in

Settings > Accessibility > Typing Assist

Refer the correct settings as per image attached here on what settings it should be configured to fix this issue

[Typing Assist Correct Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNMly.jpg)

FYI, I am able to access normal ( non Xorg ubuntu ) earlier when I realized that I actually can press the keyboard, just that it takes really2 hard to notice that the keyboard respond weirdly, so what I do is

- I spam the Alt + F4 as many times until the terminal appear
- Then I login via the terminal
- from here I `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and comment line WaylandEnable
- then i `sudo reboot`
- then at the lock screen page the ubuntu without xorg selection is available

Comment: Update : Need to disable also the Sticky Keys

Answer (score 0):

Updating the kernel version worked for me. Try upgrading to newest kernel version.
I used following blog as cheat sheet for installing new version of linux kernel. You can refer the same.
[See blog for cheat sheet](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-linux-kernal-5-19-on-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/)

In my case when i installed ubuntu 22.04 it was shipped with default kernel version of (**linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic**). Later on I installed **linux-image-6.5.7-060507-generic** and everything started working fine for me.